# Implementing a dictionary function to calculate the average of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

As always, I've attempted this for awhile before I proceed to ask a question on here. I know there are several attempts at answering this, but none really worked for what I needed.

Here are the instructions:

Implement the following three functions (you should use an appropriate looping construct to compute the averages):

```
allNumAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list.
posNumAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list that are greater than zero.
nonPosAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list that are less than or equal to zero.
```

Write a program that asks the user to enter some numbers (positives, negatives and zeros). Your program should NOT ask the user to enter a fixed number of numbers. Also it should NOT ask for the number of numbers the user wants to enter. But rather it should ask the user to enter a few numbers and end with -9999 (a sentinel value). The user can enter the numbers in any order. Your program should NOT ask the user to enter the positive and the negative numbers separately.

Your program then should create a list with the numbers entered (make sure NOT to include the sentinel value (-9999) in this list) and output the list and a dictionary with the following Key-Value pairs (using the input list and the above functions):

```
Key = 'AvgPositive'  :  Value = the average of all the positive numbers
Key = 'AvgNonPos'  :  Value = the average of all the non-positive numbers
Key = 'AvgAllNum'  :  Value = the average of all the numbers
```

Sample run:

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  4

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -3

Enter a number (-9999 to end): -15

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  0

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  10

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  22

Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -9999

The list of all numbers entered is:

[4, -3, -15, 0, 10, 22]

The dictionary with averages is:

{'AvgPositive': 12.0, 'AvgNonPos': -6.0, 'AvgAllNum': 3.0}

Here's is my code:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
dictionary = {}
total = 0

print("Enter positive, negative or zero to determine the average: ")
while(True):
    user_input = int(input("Enter a number (-9999 to end): "))
    if(user_input == -9999):
        break

def allNumAvg(values):
    for number in a:
        total = total + number
        average = sum(total) / len(total)
        if user_input > 0 or user_input < 0:
            a.append(user_input)
    return average


def posNumAvg(values):
    for number in b:
        total = total + number
        average = sum(total) / len(total)
        if user_input > 0:
            b.append(user_input)
    return average

def nonPosAvg(values):
    for number in c:
        total = total + number
        average = sum(total) + len(total)
        if user_input < 0:
            c.append(user_input)
    return average

print("The list of all numbers entered is:")
print(a+b+c)

dictionary = {
    "AvgPositive": posNumAvg(values),
    "AvgNonPos": nonPosAvg(values),
    "AvgAllNum": allNumAvg(values)
}



print("The dictionary with the averages are:")
print(dictionary)
```

My question is how can I implement the averages to be printed from the dictionary since I'm currently getting the error of:    `"AvgPositive": posNumAvg(values), NameError: name 'values' is not defined`.  Additionally, how would I get the list of the numbers entered to print?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have some confusion concerning parameters and references. You can read more about functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: I don't think you have declared **values** variable anywhere

Comment: `values` actually is declared, but only as the formal parameter of each function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something more like:

```
print("Enter positive, negative or zero to determine the average: ")
# get list of values/numbers from the user
values = [i for i in iter(lambda: int(input("Enter a number (-9999 to end): ")), -9999)]
```

`-9999` is the sentinel value to break the loop

```
def allNumAvg(values):
    # get average of all numbers
    return sum(values) / len(values)


def posNumAvg(values):
    # get only positive numbers
    values = [v for v in values if v > 0]
    return sum(values) / len(values)

def nonPosAvg(values):
    # get all negative numbers
    values = [v for v in values if v < 0]
    return sum(values) / len(values)

print("The list of all numbers entered is:")

# pass list of values to each function
dictionary = {
    "AvgPositive": posNumAvg(values),
    "AvgNonPos": nonPosAvg(values),
    "AvgAllNum": allNumAvg(values)
}
```

If you want to create the three lists in the loop check the each i in a for loop appending to the correct list:

```
a = [] # all
p = [] # pos
n = [] # neg

print("Enter positive, negative or zero to determine the average: ")
values = []
for i in iter(lambda: int(input("Enter a number (-9999 to end): ")), -9999):
    if i >= 0: # if positive append to p
        p.append(i)
    else: # else must be negative so append to n
        n.append(i)
    a.append(i) # always add to a to get all nums


def allNumAvg(values):
    return sum(values) / len(values)

def posNumAvg(values):
    return sum(values) /len(values)

def nonPosAvg(values):
    return sum(values) / len(values)

print("The list of all numbers entered is:")

# pass correct list to each function
dictionary = {
    "AvgPositive": posNumAvg(n),
    "AvgNonPos": nonPosAvg(p),
    "AvgAllNum": allNumAvg(a)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple yet I keep over thinking all of these and adding to much additional information.

Comment: @mur7ay, no prob, we have all been there.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this...(you can debug if it doesn't work as-is, since it's homework!). you need to define 'values'

```
values = []

print("Enter positive, negative or zero to determine the average: ")
while(True):
    user_input = int(input("Enter a number (-9999 to end): "))
    if(user_input == -9999):
        break
    values.append(user_input)
```

that should get you started.

Comment: Thank you! That helped. For some reason I kept thinking that there needed to be three different list for each def function.